# jQuery - trigger a custom event on a link

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to run this custom 'getOffer()' event using jQuery

```
<a href="javascript: void getOffer();" title="Submit for offer"><img src="images/img.jpeg"></a>
```

I have tried the following but it doesn't seem to work (I am using the Firefox Firebug console.log window)

```
$('a[title="Submit for offer"]').trigger('getOffer');
```

This is the page I am trying this on: http://bit.ly/1dpIMFk
Can anyone suggest any ideas?

Comment: Its on an external site that I do not have the ability to change id or name unfortunately. The selector does seem to work - however it would seem the trigger() part doesn't

Comment: `$element.on('getOffer', getOffer);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <a href="javascript: void getOffer();" title="Submit for offer"><img src="images/img.jpeg"></a>

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a[title="Submit for offer"]').trigger('getOffer');
});

function getOffer(){
alert('link clicked');
}
```

Seems working fine for me.I think you didnt wrapped your event trigger in document ready.
**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/EdUBepo/1/edit)**

Comment: This is not a custom event, to do so you could call the function directly

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
<a href="#" onClick="getOffer();"><img src="images/img.jpeg"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Creating an custom event on jQuery

First add some identifier (id/class) to your link

```
<a id="linkOffer" title="Submit for offer"><img src="images/img.jpeg"></a>
```

Then, create your CUSTOM event.

```
//The function that will to the getOffer things
function getOffer() {
    //Do get offer...  
}

$(document).ready(function(){

    //Custom event pointing to the function
    $('a#linkOffer').on('getoffer',getOffer);

    //Default click event
    $('a#linkOffer').on('click',function(e){
         //Do click stuff.

         //Trigger your custom event.
         $(this).trigger('getoffer');

         //If you wish to not move the page, prevent the default link click behavior (moveing to other page)
         e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Trigger will not function because it search `click` attribute in element. Work around for this can be is:

Add click attribute to the element and then call the jquery function.

```
<a href="javascript: void getOffer();" title="Submit for offer"></a>
    <button value="yu" onclick="getOffer();"/>
<script>

 $("a[title='Submit for offer']").attr("onclick",$("a[title='Submit for offer']").attr('href')); // get value from href
 $("a[title='Submit for offer']").trigger('click');  


 function getOffer()
 {
     alert('j');
 }
</script>
```